# logstash jmx input plugin returns just %{message}

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I'm using the JMX input plugin in logstash to pull Kafka mbean but for some reason it just returns lines like this and I get the right line count for each mbean but not the values, just `%{message}`:

```
2017-02-10T22:40:20.836Z 0.0.0.0 %{message}
2017-02-10T22:40:20.837Z 0.0.0.0 %{message}
2017-02-10T22:40:20.838Z 0.0.0.0 %{message}
2017-02-10T22:40:20.841Z 0.0.0.0 %{message}
2017-02-10T22:40:20.843Z 0.0.0.0 %{message}
...
```

my logstash conf file looks like this:

```
input {
jmx {
  path => "/home/usrxxx/logstash-5.2.0/bin/jmxconf"
  polling_frequency => 5
  nb_thread => 4
}

}
output {
  stdout {  }
}
```

and then my jmx json conf looks like this:

```
{
  "host" : "0.0.0.0",
  "port" : 9999,
  "alias" : "kafkabroker1",
  "queries" : [
  {
    "object_name" : "kafka.server:type=BrokerTopicMetrics,name=*"
  } ]
}
```

I've also tried `localhost` and the actual hostname too for `host`...any idea on why it just returns `%{message}` and not the mbean values?

Comment: Can you try either the `json` or `rubydebug` codec in your `stdout` output?

Comment: yep...that worked!